# AWS file load works on localhost, but doesn't work on EC2 (node, express, react). Get 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, multer

I have application on Node. API endpoint for sending files to AWS contains this part

```
const multer = require('multer');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: require("../config/keys").aws.key,
  accessKeyId: require("../config/keys").aws.id,
  region: 'eu-central-1'
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: require("../config/keys").aws.bucket,
  key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now().toString());
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

I call it in route this way

```
const upload = require('../../middleware/multer-aws');

router.post("/add", upload.any('file'), (req, res) => {
...
```

When I test loading files on localhost it works well, but when I do the same on EC2 instance I have **403 Forbidden** response.

In my code I don't have 403 codes, so it definetely comes from AWS.

I can't get where is the problem and how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you validated the permissions of files and directories for the code base? Also where is the 403 being returned from? Your application or the AWS CLI?

Comment: I didn't change anything in code. Just pulled the same code on EC2. Basically application works well, but this part doesn't. I can't get where 403 comes from. As I understand from multer part, when it tries to upload file on server. In my application I don't have 403 codes.

Comment: Can you validate the key and secret key are being retrieved in the application?

Comment: I made logs, and see that they are correct

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some NACL issue outbound HTTP access might be blocked from the EC2 instance, if AWS access keys and secret keys are perfectly working in local instance and uploading files to S3, it should have worked from EC2, please check NACL

Answer (score -1):

Issue solved. I checked pm2 logs, found message about InvalidAccessKeyId. Checked env variable and found, that I messed key and id on prod.

Comment: getting error in ec2 (403) for file upload , not uploading to ec2 but keeping in memory and uploading to third party